# How to get a specific icon flag using famfamfam flag icons for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, icons

I'm learning WPF and I needed to use the flags icons in the application.
I decided to use [famfamfam flag icons for WPF](https://github.com/point-platform/famfamfam-flags-wpf) but I can not understand how to get a single or a pair of flags from the set.
The only thing that the author offered as an example is a complete list of all the flags that I do not need:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static flags:CountryData.AllCountries}}">
```

Comment: flags:CountryData.AllCountries is a static collection, in your ViewModel you can create a new instance add only those flags which you require. And in XAML you can bind the new collection.

Comment: is there an example how to create a collection of this kind?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do to get the flag of Afghanistan in XAML:

```
<Image Source="/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf;component/Images/af.png"/>
```

---

Or in C#:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
    Flag_Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf;component/Images/af.png", UriKind.Relative));
});
```

---

I agree that the documention is lacking a little!